# local language getting converted to alien language on page load in javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-2013

I want my page to show certain texts in a hindi language when the language chosen is Hindi.

My code:

```
 function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
        var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                c = c.substring(1);
            }
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
    function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
        document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
    }


if ((currentUiCluture != null) && (currentUiCluture != undefined) && (currentUiCluture != "")) {
                if (currentUiCluture == 'hi-IN') {
                    $('#AmtFYyear').text(yr  + "वित्त वर्ष के लिए जिलावार अर्जित राशि " + "(करोड़ रुपये में)");                
                }
                if (currentUiCluture == 'en-US') {
                    $('#AmtFYyear').text("District wise Accrued Amount for FY  " + yr + " (Rs in Cr.)");
               }
            }
            else
            {
                 $('#AmtFYyear').text("District wise Accrued Amount for FY  " + yr + " (Rs in Cr.)");           
            }
```

But वित्त वर्ष के लिए जिलावार अर्जित राशि gets converted to à¤¡à¥‡à¤Ÿà¤¾ à¤‰à¤ªà¤²à¤¬à¥à¤§ à¤¨à¤¹à¥€à¤‚

Initially i thought its due to empty spaces but that also couldn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You are close Just use `decodeURI(row)` like the following :

`source: ["first","second",decodeURI("वित्त वर्ष के लिए")]`